# What is the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $\frac{2\tan x}{1+4x^2}$ around $x=0?$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

What is the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $\frac{2\tan x}{1+4x^2}$ around $x=0?$

I have to find out $a_n=\frac {f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$, but the $n-$th  derivative of the given function is not easy to handle. Please help. Thanks,

Comment: Hint: What are the smallest complex zeros of numerator and denominator? ("smallest" is to be understood in the sense of the absolute value!)

Comment: $\frac{i}{2}$ and $\frac{-i}{2}$

Comment: Absolutely ;-) So what conclusion can you draw on the *maximum* radius of convergence of your function?

Answer (score 2):

If Complex Analysis is allowed: Let $P:=\{(2k+1) \frac{\pi}{2}:k \in \mathbb Z\} \cup \{\frac{i}{2},-\frac{i}{2}\}$ and $f(z):=\frac{2 \tan(z)}{1+4z^2}$.

Then $f$ is holomorphic on $ \mathbb C \setminus P$.

Hence the radius of convergence in question is given by

$$ \min \{|0-p|: p \in P\}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: im not getting how $ min {|0-p|: p\in P} = \frac{1}{2} $}

Answer (score 1):

Hint. The function $f(x):=\frac{2\tan x}{1+4x^2}$ is odd and the coefficient of $x^{2n+1}$  of its Taylor expansion at $0$  is equal to
$$b_{2n+1}=2[x^{2n+1}]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{2k+1} x^{2k+1}\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-4x^2)^{k}\\=2(a_{2n+1}-4a_{2n-1}+4^2a_{2n-3}+\dots +(-4)^na_1)$$
where $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{2k+1} x^{2k+1}$ is the Taylor's series at $0$ of $\tan(x)$.

Notice that $a_{2n+1}\sim \frac{C}{(\pi/2)^{2n+1}}$ (see for example [Calculate and justify why one has this asymptotic for the nth odd coefficient of the tangent function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901901/calculate-and-justify-why-one-has-this-asymptotic-for-the-nth-odd-coefficient-of)).
Show that
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[2n+1]{|b_{2n+1}|}=2$$
and therefore the radius of convergence is $1/2$.

Comment: How can I prove your last limit expression, I tried but not getting.

Comment: $|b_{2n+1}|\sim C\cdot 4^n$

Comment: How your last comment came into picture

Comment: $$|b_{2n+1}|/4^n\leq 2(|a_{2n+1}|/4^n+|a_{2n-1}|/4^{n-1}+a_{2n-3}/4^{n-2}+\dots +|a_1|)<+\infty$$

Comment: @RobertZ...as  im not getting  how u write  2nd line  of  ur answer ??? i mean it should be$ f(x) := \frac{2\tan x}{1+4x^2}$ is odd and the coefficient of $x^{2n+1}$  of its Taylor expansion at $0$  is equal to
$$\frac{2\tan x}{1+4x^2}=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{2n+1}\frac{ x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-4x^2)^{k}$$

Comment: pliz verified @RobertZ

Comment: u can comment on my  post ?as i  have  post this question ..

Comment: You are using the Taylor expansion of $\arctan(x)$. Here we have $\tan(x)$.