# What is the radius of convergence of the Taylor series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

What is the  radius of convergence  of the taylor series of$ \frac{2\tan x}{1+4x^2}$  around $x = 0$ ?

my attempsts:The function $f(x) := \frac{2\tan x}{1+4x^2}$ is odd and the coefficient of $x^{2n+1}$  of its Taylor expansion at $0$  is equal to
$$\frac{2\tan x}{1+4x^2}=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{2n+1}\frac{ x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-4x^2)^{k}$$

Now  i can not able proceed further ...pliz help  as i have found this 
 solution  but i did not understand this...solution me...[What is the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $\frac{2\tan x}{1+4x^2}$ around $x=0?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662932/what-is-the-radius-of-convergence-of-the-taylor-series-of-frac2-tan-x14x2)

Comment: Are allowed to use resultas from Complex Analysis?

Comment: no complex analysis  is not allowed @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: @gimusi...as  i didn't  understand this solution

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos,,,but  im not understanding this solution

Comment: Nevertheless, your question is a duplicate. If you don't understand the answer, post your doubts as a comment to that answer.